# c++ win32 dynamic menu - which menu item was selected

Tags: c++, winapi, menu, selected, submenu

i have a win32 application (c++) that has a context menu bind to the right click on the notify icon. The menu/submenu items are dynamicly created and changed during runtime.

```
 InsertMenu(hSettings, 0, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_POPUP | MF_STRING, (UINT_PTR) hDevices, L"Setting 1");
 InsertMenu(hSettings, 1, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_POPUP | MF_STRING, (UINT_PTR) hChannels, L"Setting 2");

 InsertMenu(hMainMenu, 0, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_POPUP | MF_STRING, (UINT_PTR) hSettings, L"Settings");
 InsertMenu(hMainMenu, 1, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_STRING, IDM_EXIT, L"Exit");
```

In the code above hDevices and hChannels are dynamicly generated sub menus. 
The dynamic menus are generated like this:

```
   InsertMenu(hDevices, i, style, IDM_DEVICE, L"Test 1");
   InsertMenu(hDevices, i, style, IDM_DEVICE, L"Test 2");
   InsertMenu(hDevices, i, style, IDM_DEVICE, L"Test 3");
```

Is there any way of knowing which item was clicked without having to define each submenu item it's own ID (IDM_DEVICE in the code above)? In would like to detect that user clicked on submenu IDM_DEVICE and that he clicked on the first item (Test 1) in this submenu.

I would like to achive something like this:

```
  case WM_COMMAND:
    wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
    wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
    // Parse the menu selections:
    switch (wmId)
    {
        case IDM_DEVICE: // user clicked on Test 1 or Test 2 or Test 3 
            UINT index = getClickedMenuItem(); // get the index number of the clicked item (if you clicked on Test 1 it would be 0,..) 
                            // change the style of the menu item with that index 
            break;          
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following:

```
MENUINFO mi;
memset(&mi, 0, sizeof(mi));
mi.cbSize = sizeof(mi);
mi.fMask = MIM_STYLE;
mi.dwStyle = MNS_NOTIFYBYPOS;
SetMenuInfo(hDevices, &mi);
```

Now you'll get the `WM_MENUCOMMAND` instead of `WM_COMMAND`. The menu index will be in wParam and the menu handle in lParam. Take care to eat up messages only for known menus and past the rest to `DefWindowProc`. The code will be similar to this:

```
case WM_MENUCOMMAND:
    HMENU menu = (HMENU)lParam;
    int idx = wParam;
    if (menu == hDevices)
    {
       //Do useful things with device #idx
    }
    else
        break; //Ensure that after that there is a DefWindowProc call
```

Answer (score 0):

One can also use `TrackPopupMenuEx()` with the flags `TPM_RETURNCMD | TPM_NONOTIFY` and get the `id` of the selected menu item without having to go thru `WM_MENUCOMMAND`.